# How to send asyncronous response when calling MethodChannel?

Tags: flutter, flutter-method-channel

Flutter official documentation says we can't use EventChannel for both-direction communication between Flutter and Native code, only on listening events from Native.

So the MethodChannel is the only recommended way to call a method on native from Flutter code. My problem is that I'm using a Thermal Printer that calls an asynchronous routine to print, including internal listeners that run outside the main UI thread.
This is the error that I get:

```
/JavaBinder( 6792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Binder_2
```

That way I can't use a simple Future to return something to Flutter, because I can't send results from listeners.

**Question**: How can I create an EventChannel whose EventSink can be accessed by a MethodChannel call?

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "unique.identifier.method/call";
    private static final String CHANNEL_STREAM = "unique.identifier.method/stream";
    private Printer printer = new Printer(getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                (call, result) -> {
                    // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                    String method = call.method;
                    if(method == "print"){
                        printer.startPrint(new OnPrintListener.Stub() {
                            public void onFinish() throws RemoteException {
                                printer.cutPaper();
                                //Question: how to send event from this point?
                            }
                            public void onError(int i) throws RemoteException {
                                //Question: how to send error event from this point?
                                throw new RemoteException("Print exception: "+i);
                            }
                        });
                        //it returns true before printing has been finished 
                        result.success(true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: *"java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Binder_2"* -   tried using [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler?hl=en#Handler(android.os.Looper)) with [main](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper?hl=en#getMainLooper()) `Looper`?

Comment: Nope, do you have any functional example to share?

Comment: `handler.post(your Runnable that calls printer.startPrint method)`

Comment: I just tested it and it worked! I was using the `runOnUIThread` method and I got an error, but when I used the `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable)` my problem was solved and I could use `EventSink` instance. I also just found this reference in the official documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#jumping-to-the-ui-thread-in-android. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sure, your welcome, notice that you can also use one of: `sendEmptyMessage*()` or `sendMessage*()` methods